# The font colors not appearing in Android Studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio

[The text colors disappeared in Android Studio. All texts are white and indistinguishable. Is anyone experiencing this issue, and what is the solution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxu2W.png)

Just wanted to check out how the themes were, so I was changing the themes. I don't exactly remember if I played with a setting, but I don't think I did; I just wanted to add a theme. I added it and then deleted it.

Comment: The file you edit is  JavaScript file, but the content is XML, how should Android Studio format such a file? Most likely the screenshot shows a JavaScript string containing XML data, then the string is formatted as a whole. Just don't write XML as String inside JavaScript.

Comment: No, there is no XML. It's react native and i only use js.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that the primary structure is HTML/XML code and not JavaScript code. JavaScript does not make use of elements like `<TextInput ...>`

Comment: So if it's like you said, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: May be start using the correct file extension? `.html` for html files, `.xml` for XML files and `.js` for JavaScript files.